# Add element in the beginning of a list which extracted from a dataframe

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, pandas

I wanted to add an element at the beginning of a list which is extracted from a pandas dataframe. Below is my example.

```
import pandas as pd
dat = pd.DataFrame({'X' : [1,2], 'Y' : ['A', 'B']})
[999] + dat['X'].values
### array([1000, 1001])
```

I wanted to add element 999 at the beginning but python is adding that value to each element.

Can you please help me to find the approach?

Comment: `[999] + list(dat['X'].values)` does the trick. `df.values` returns an instance of `np.array` which causes `999` to be added to each element through broadcasting. Andrej's example in the comment below is even better mine.

Comment: Or: `[999, *dat["X"]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `pd.concat()` for data frame column or `list.insert()` for a simple list, `list.insert()` takes the index where you want to insert your new value as the first argument and the value as the second argument.
`pd.concat()` takes the value you want to insert then the column of the data frame if you want it to be inserted at the beginning it must at this order.